# Join on two tables without a unique key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a program that imports data and sends emails out. I have another process which stores the smtp email log information.

I use the email log for reporting so that I can provide users with information e.g. bounced, delivered etc...

The problem I have is that the user wants the Account number which is stored in the other table of email info i.e. not the smtp email log.

The only way I can currently tie the two tables together is by email address and date. This will be enough most of the time to find the correct account number.

The problem is where there could be 3 emails sent from different accounts with the same email address on the same day e.g.

```
Account number Email Address     Date 
----------------------------------------------
1              email@address.com 9/12/2016 
2              email@address.com 9/12/2016 
3              email@address.com 9/12/2016
```

When I join the two tables as follows :-

```
select l.event, l.[time], l.SendTime, l.Recipient, e.AccountNumber from emaillog l 
OUTER APPLY 
(SELECT TOP 1 AccountNumber from emailData e 
where e.EmailAddress = l.Recipient and Convert(date, [DateEmailed]) = Convert(date, l.Time) 
) as e 
where Convert(date, l.Time) = '2016-12-09';
```

I got

```
Account number Email Address     Date 
--------------------------------------------- 
1              email@address.com 9/12/2016 
1              email@address.com 9/12/2016 
1              email@address.com 9/12/2016
```

i.e. It always finds the first record in my email table because the email address and date match.

Is there any way I can get the correct account number back?

I did think about writing an SP that creates a temporary table from the email log, finds the multiple entries then says something like for log row 1 put in the account number for row 1 in the email data table.

I am just wondering if I have missed a SQL trick or two!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are really using.

Comment: I added the `sql-server` tag based on the non standard `[..]` and `outer apply`

Comment: Sorry, yes it is SQL-Server

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead, enumerate the emails and the responses, suggesting:

```
select l.event, l.[time], l.SendTime, l.Recipient, ed.AccountNumber
from (select l.*,
             row_number() over (partition by recipient, Convert(date, [DateEmailed] order by dateemailed) as seqnum
      from emaillog as l 
     ) as l left join
     (select ed.*
             row_number() over (partition by recipient, Convert(date, [time] order by time) as seqnum
      from emaildata as ed
     ) as ed
     on ed.EmailAddress = l.Recipient and ed.seqnum = l.seqnum
where Convert(date, l.Time) = '2016-12-09';
```

Comment: Is there a reason for the anonymous downvote?  What is the issue with the answer?

Comment: Hi, that code doesn't appear to work, syntax errors e.g. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 'row_number'.

Comment: @AceGrace What version of SQL Server are you using? Is it by any chance 2008R2 or older?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu . . . `row_number()` was introduced in SQL Server 2005.  Hence it is in every supported version of SQL Server.  It is possible to have compatibility levels set so it is not supported.

Comment: @GordonLinoff row_number() has been introduced in SQL Server 2005, but the `PARTITION BY` is available from 2008R2 onwards I believe. So, that's why he might be getting the syntax error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Nevermind, I got it confused with `SUM() OVER (ORDER BY)`, [from a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40787091/how-to-increase-counter-in-select/40787256#comment68797226_40787256).

Answer (score 0):

There were some syntax issues so I will post the corrected code BUT Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I am pretty rusty with SQL server.

```
   select l.event, l.[time], l.SendTime, l.Recipient, ed.AccountNumber
from (select l.*,
             row_number() over (partition by recipient, Convert(date, [time]) order by [time]) as seqnum
      from emaillog as l 
     ) as l left join
     (select ed.*,
             row_number() over (partition by emailaddress, Convert(date, [DateEmailed])  order by [DateEmailed]) as seqnum
      from ebilldata as ed
     ) as ed
     on ed.EmailAddress = l.Recipient and ed.seqnum = l.seqnum
where Convert(date, l.Time) = '2016-12-06';
```